# Phonegap and windows phone native frame transition

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I'm trying to find some docs to learn how to make phonegap app for windows phone, using native frame transition for HTML pages, but I cannot find such a plugin or code or any helpful doc.

What exactly I want to do is:

when I try to navigate to other page in HTML code using javascript code:

```
window.location.href = "newpage.html";
```

I want my app to navigate to different page like native app is doing transition effect, for example when app start we can see this page/frame transition effect.

How to do that transition effect for HTML pages ?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using jQuery Mobile to build HTML pages for a Phonegap app.

http://jquerymobile.com

It's useful because it has a built-in router, which can detect when you try to change to another HTML page. (either programatically or via a user clicking on links)

It then can hijack that event and make it load the next page asynchronously (which in the case of a Phonegap app, is pretty fast since the pages already exist on the device). It then applies the transitions you speak of when it displays the new page (slide, fade, etc).

It's quite customisable, and most of the behaviour is configured by just creating simple HTML markup and adding data attributes. E.g.

```
<a href="next-page.html" data-role="button" data-transition="flow">next page</a>
```

I also like it because if you decide you want to go down the "single page app" route - you can do that too. I personally like the combination of Phonegap + jQuery Mobile + Backbone.js, where Backbone.js is dynamically generating my HTML jQuery Mobile pages, and Phonegap is wrapping them up in an app.

Comment: Did you tried in WP7 phonegap project, it is working ?  
Because I tried and not working

Comment: @JigsweelJigsweel, no I haven't, but it should work fine in WP7. Nothing I have said is specific to any particular phone vendor so it should work with anything that Phonegap and jQuery Mobile support. I would suggest that if it's not working for you, then there's an issue in how you have created your jQuery Mobile page. jQuery mobile is just HTML - so get it working in your desktop browser first. Then add the HTML files into your Phonegap project. If you're still having trouble, post some more questions to SO.

Comment: Not working in WP7, I tried also just to open external link: http://coenraets.org/apps/directory/jqm/index.html   the page have no transition effect and design is very ugly.

Comment: @JigsweelJigsweel, the default styles can be changed. I often use it without their styles and add my own custom skin. The point of it is more for their framework/behaviours than the look and feel.

I would say if the transitions aren't working, then WP7 doesn't have great support for CSS3 transitions. I suppose you can google around and see if you can change the default transitions in jQuery Mobile to use a different implementation. I would expect the performance to not be great - the advantage of CSS3 transitions is that they are GPU accelerated, which is important for mobile devices.